# Streamreader and streamwriter for displaying html pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using html editor for editing pages. From what I understand the editor is using streamreader for displaying the page and streamwriter for saving the changes.

The problem is that the streamreader.readtoend() returns a string of the page to the editor but it doesn't show the css properties.

Any idea of how to get a full picture of the page include the css on server side?

Comment: You would have to parse the HTML page and get references to those things. You might consider the HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string you got from `streamreader.readtoend()` for all `<link href="....css" ...>` and download them too.

Comment: can you give me example of how to parse the link?why is the streamreader ignore those links?

Comment: streamreader itself will not do anything but help you read whatever is written. Parsing and further download must be done by you.

Answer (score -1):

In short, not really.  CSS by its nature is client-side/rendered.

Comment: can someone give me short example how to parse the stylesheet links and add them to the text result ?